# Retrieve Steam game data using API request

Tags: api, steam, steam-web-api

I'd like to know how to create an API call to the Steam web API in order to retrieve all the relevant data for a specified game.  I found an example call that almost does what I need, except this call requires you to know the Steam app ID as you can see below:

http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?appids=730

As you can see if you click on the link, all the information I need is returned with the API call.  However I'd like to know if it's possible to modify this API call so that it returns the required information using the game **name** rather than the Steam ID number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think this is possible (although the lack of official documentation of the API means I may be wrong).

Firstly, from a design perspective it probably wouldn't work - games could have the same name and so name is not a unique enough reference to identify an item (which is a fundamental concept of a correctly designed REST API).

Secondly, all examples ([such as this here](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/User:RJackson/StorefrontAPI#Known_methods)) I have come across on the web of people self-documenting the API use appID to identify a game/software and have found no cases of being able to use name. The other [documented Steam DEV APIs](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetNewsForApp_.28v0001.29) also use AppId

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I guess I'll have to look somewhere other than Steam for getting game.  I've just stumbled across a site called Giant Bomb that seems like it may be able to do what I need.

Comment: Great - hope that works for you!

Having a think, if that doesn't work for you maybe a solution would be to look at making two API calls, one to get all software/games (http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0001) then within your code search or filter that response to find the JSON object you want with the name of the game you are looking for (will have to deal with the scenario of potentially multiple matches) then extract the appID which you can then use to call the original API endpoint.

Comment: That sounds like a great backup plan, I'll definitely give that a try if the other approach doesn't pan out.  Thanks Gaz.